# Combine amp-analytics for amp-next-page

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, analytics, amp-html

I am currently using the code below to track pageviews on my AMP accelerated pages on a WordPress website:

```
    {
    "vars": {
        "account": "UA-12345678-1"
    },
    "triggers": {
        "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "pageview"
        }
    }
}
```

I have just implemented infinite scroll on single pages and i need the next-page to be tracked on scroll or click also. I found the below code on the official "amp.dev" page:

```
 <amp-analytics>
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "requests": {
        "nextpage": "https://example.com/pixel?RANDOM&toURL=${toURL}"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "trackScrollThrough": {
          "on": "amp-next-page-scroll",
          "request": "nextpage"
        },
        "trackClickThrough": {
          "on": "amp-next-page-click",
          "request": "nextpage"
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

How can I combine both codes into one such that it can track both pageviews and the infinite scroll (both on-click and on-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a work-around, i added the code below in my footer and it works:

```
<amp-analytics id="11e2c333333a" type="googleanalytics">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "requests": {
        "nextpage": "<?php get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>?amp"
      },
    "vars": {
        "account": "UA-12345678-1"
    },
      "triggers": {
        "trackScrollThrough": {
          "on": "amp-next-page-scroll",
          "request": "nextpage"
        },
        "trackClickThrough": {
          "on": "amp-next-page-click",
          "request": "nextpage"
        },
    "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "pageview"
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```